# Function with parameter in Openquery

Tags: t-sql, function, parameters, return, openquery

I am trying to create a function that uses the parameter in an OpenQuery like below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnMyFunction (@myVar INT) RETURNS TABLE AS
    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000)
SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServer, ''SELECT num FROM tblMyTable WHERE
myTableNum = '+ @myVar + '  '')'

RETURN EXEC(@Query)
```

The Openquery should return only a single integer. I've tried

```
...RETURNS INT AS
...OPENQUERY...
DECLARE @num INT
SET @num = 0
@num = EXEC(@Query)
RETURN @num
```

and get A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Comment: Use a stored procedure instead of a function.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think you can use this type of call (`openquery`) in a function.

User-Defined functions do not allow for dynamic SQL and that is considered dynamic SQL.

So I believe your only option would be to create a stored procedure to return that value.  Or create a temp table inline and use it in your stored procedure before using it.

Here is an article with [other limitations of UDFs](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/29/sql-server-user-defined-functions-udf-limitations/)

You would have to just make that call before using it:

```
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @myVar INT
SET @myVar = yourValue

SET @Query = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(myLinkedServer, ''SELECT num FROM tblMyTable WHERE
myTableNum = '+ @myVar + '  '')'

EXEC(@Query)
```